# Installing bcache on debian9

Tags: debian, software-installation, bcache

I am installing bcache tools on my debian-9 machine

```
root@machine# uname -a
Linux singlefs-ssd-vm 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u3 (2017-08-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Commands tried:

```
make-bcache -B /dev/sdx1
make-bcache --block 4k --bucket 2M -C /dev/sdy2

echo cset.uuid > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/attach
```

where cset.uuid is

```
bcache-super-show /dev/sdy2 | grep cset.uuid | awk '{print $2}'
```

Error thrown in /var/log/syslog

```
Oct  9 10:40:24 localhost kernel: [  110.511712] bcache: bch_cached_dev_attach() Couldn't attach sdb: block size less than set's block size
Oct  9 10:40:24 localhost kernel: [  110.513014] bcache: __cached_dev_store() Can't attach xxxx
Oct  9 10:40:24 localhost kernel: [  110.513014] : cache set not found
```

fdisk -l gives

```
Disk /dev/sdx1: 1.5 TiB, 1610612736000 bytes, 3145728000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/bcache0: 1.5 TiB, 1610612727808 bytes, 3145727984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

you should specify "--block 4k" for backing device as well

```
make-bcache --block 4k -B /dev/sdx1
```